# Getting 403 Forbidden error on centos server after changing usergroup

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

Can anyone please help me to find what will be the reason for getting 403 Forbidden error on my domain http://e-learning.rawlanguages.com/.

Its a linux centos server after I change user group, I am getting 403 Forbidden error and not able to access site.

This is the directory permission

```
drwxrwxrwx.  9 RL   root   103 Apr  6 20:12 sentora
```

Comment: Your Web server is apache?

Comment: yes apache my web server

Comment: I opened the link but no forbidden error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some error with user group and permission, once they provide authorization, it start work.

Thank you for looking at my question